# Redrawing a FullCalendar so that the dayRender callback is called

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a FullCalendar inside a Bootstrap modal. Originally, I created the calendar on load and simply called render (ie, with `$("#calendar").fullCalendar("render")`) to make it appear. This correctly calls the `dayRender` callback, which I need to be able to do some custom rendering to the calendar.

The rendering done by `dayRender` is dynamic, so I need to be able to redo the rendering. I thought that calling render (as described above) would do this, but that doesn't seem to be the case (subsequent calls don't call `dayRender`).

The only solution I've found is to completely destroy and recreate the calendar, but this creates a very noticeable flicker (from the calendar being destroyed before it's recreated). <del>Switching between months is calling `dayRender` correctly and doesn't have this annoying flicker, so there must be some way to get the calendar to render without having to destroy and recreate it.</del>

**How can I force `dayRender` to be called on all days of the month?**

EDIT: I've created [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xr1hv4gw/1/) showing the problem. Note that when the modal is opened, there's a pause before the calendar appears. Every time we reopen the modal, a different day is given the "foo" text, to show the calendar being updated via `dayRender`. This works, but the pause before the calendar is ugly and we can see that switching between months *isn't* calling `dayRender`, as I previously thought.

[Here's a version that works *almost* the way I want it to](http://jsfiddle.net/2b6qpw8o/1/). Note that we call `render` instead. However, it apparently doesn't force `dayRender` to be called on every day. But now there's no long delay in showing the calendar. Strangely, if I change the month, then change back, the day is updated (implying that `dayRender` was called).

Comment: Haven't found a real solution to this, but the current workaround that avoids the flicker I mentioned is to actually call the `dayRender` function on each day in the calendar myself. Before you can do that, you must reset the day. This is somewhat non-trivial if you have to remove classes from the days, since you'd have to reapply several classes (including the day of the week, future, past, and current day classes). The date can fortunately be obtained via the `data-date` attribute on the cell.

Comment: I later found that there is no way to do this beyond the previously mentioned workaround. [There's a feature request for this](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2444), but as of the date of this posting, it has not been implemented.